# Heroku: Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app

Tags: javascript, heroku

I used to push my local repo into Heroku without any issue, then I had to downgrade Node from 17.3.0 to 16.14.0, afterward I have been running into this error.

Error Log on Heroku:

[image]

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "body": "^5.1.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongodb": "^4.3.0",
    "mongoose": "^6.1.8",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "node": "^16.14.0",
    "parsr": "^0.0.1",
    "passport": "^0.5.2",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.12.5",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "name": "movie",
  "description": "To build the server-side component of a “movies” web application. The web application will provide users with access to information about different movies, directors, and genres. Users will be able to sign up, update their personal information, and create a list of their favorite movies",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And here is my `package-lock.json` under the voice "package":

```
"packages": {
    "": {
      "name": "movie",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
        "body": "^5.1.0",
        "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "express": "^4.17.2",
        "express-validator": "^6.14.0",
        "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
        "mongodb": "^4.3.0",
        "mongoose": "^6.1.8",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "node": "^17.3.1",
        "parsr": "^0.0.1",
        "passport": "^0.5.2",
        "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
        "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
        "sequelize": "^6.12.5",
        "uuid": "^8.3.2"
      }
```

As you can see there are two different versions of Node reported...

`.gitignore` has already:

```
node_modules
```

What is the problem, and how can I fix it?

Comment: It seems like Heroku doesn't support Node.js 16.14.0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this one a few times ago. If your local version of node.js is not Heroku one, you should add theses lines into you package.json:

```
"engines": {
  "node": "your_node_version" // in my case it was 14.x
},
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I used a version from my Repo that worked fine and that I was able to push on Heroku. I applied what I need to change and uploaded it again without issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your package.json file. Also note that if you are using node version 16.14.0 Heroku doesn’t support this version. You can use 16.16.0 or higher.

```
"engines": {
  "node": "16.x" // in my case it was 16.x
},
```